# How do I keep a user from double clicking a link in an email?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, click, double

When users request a password reset, they get an email with a link to generate a password reset code. This link is valid for 24 hours and can be re-used within the 24 hours to generate a new code if the first is lost or forgotten. When users double click the link, two codes are getting generated, leading to user confusion about which to use (the second code invalidates the first code with the way it has been developed).

Since the link in the email is just an html a tag, I'm not sure how I can keep users from double clicking the link.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible to use javascript in an email but try this maybe it works:  
 `<a href="your_link"  onclick="window.location.href='your_link'" ondblclick="window.location.href='/'">link</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you're facing [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/184030). Your actual issue is that users get confused by visits in a quick succession causing a code that was just generated to be invalid, rather than the fact that the link can be clicked twice.

From a security point of view, these kind of links should really be single-use, and the user should request a new e-mail if they want to perform the action again. Assuming this is something you're forced to do, I believe the best compromise would be to limit code generation to a time frame, so visits within, let's say, 5-10 seconds would result in the same code being shown to the user, based on the server's time.

Implementing any CSS based solution for this that'd work across every e-mail client out there is challenging enough (if at all possible), and I doubt any self-respecting e-mail client is going to let you run any sort of JavaScript to intercept the event.

The following works in a modern browser on an actual web page, but this is not just a **bad idea**, it's also probably not going to work if you try to use it in an e-mail. I'm providing it here just for the sake of completeness, showing that it's somewhat possible, but please **do not** rely on this to fix the underlying issue.

```html
<style>a:focus { pointer-events: none }</style>
<p>This is some text, here's <a href="#try-me">a link</a> you can't double click by the way.</p>
```